# Loading external data in processingjs

Tags: data-visualization, processing.js

We want to create a web-based interactive visualization tool to make sense of data that we work with (for those interested: it's about next-generation DNA sequencing data). One of the issues we bump into at the moment is how to get the data to the tool. Apparently this javascript library cannot load external data, and as far as I understand the data would actually have to be embedded in the html itself. This is however out of the question as we're dealing with patient data here...

Does anyone have any pointers as to how we can access external data (basically .csv files) from processing.js?

Thanks!
jan.

Comment: If possible, I'd like to see a demo or the finished project someday.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason you couldn't load it via another library, such as jQuery, and then integrate it into your app.  Here's [an example of this](http://blog.osmeusapontamentos.com/processing/ex_pag33.htm).  Basically, you would load the data, and then access it via PJS once it is available.

PJS is parsed to javascript, so the opportunities for integrating with any regular JS code are very good.

Comment: the linked example is offline: 404

Answer (score 0):

Processing.js can load external data, for example using the function [loadStrings](http://processingjs.org/reference/loadStrings_/).

To make data available to your script, create a `Data` directory in your processing project, put your data files in there, and then load them up using loadStrings or loadXML.

---

Note that the documentation page is a little confused about whether its talking about processing.org (java) or processing.js (JavaScript backend).  Just ignore the stuff about signed applets; there's no special reason processing.js can only read from the same site.